# Iptable ordering of commands

Tags: networking, iptables, policy

When adding a new rule in iptable I want it to be the first command to be executed, which means it will go on top of the rules list. What do I have to add in the command to change its position on the list.

my command: `sudo iptables -s 10.1.10.201 -j DROP`

Comment: Please can you post the result for `iptables -L -n -v` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To place a rule at a specific spot in the rule set for a specific chain, give it a rule number. Meaning, instead of:

```
sudo iptables -s 10.1.10.201 -j DROP
```

which is missing both a chain (or table) designation and a rule number, do this:

```
sudo iptables I INPUT 1 -s 10.1.10.201 -j DROP
```

I just used `INPUT` as an example, you do whatever it is you are trying to do. However, I specified to insert the rule as the first rule.

Please read the [man pages for iptables](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/iptables.8.html). For example this is an extract:

```
 -I, --insert chain [rulenum] rule-specification
              Insert one or more rules in the selected chain as the given rule number.  So, if the rule number is 1, the rule or rules are inserted at the head of the chain.  This  is  also  the
              default if no rule number is specified.
```